# Defining city name by using KMZ files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, geocoding, overlay, kmz

We have KMZ files of different satellite images. We want to check which cities these satellite images belong to. Is there a way to do it automaticly? Like a tool in ArcGIS or QGIS or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "KML to layer" tool in ArcGIS for Desktop.  As long as there is meta data associated with your image this tool will convert the images from KML and then they should plot over your basemap.

Comment: Just had another thought.  You should be able to use ArcGIS Earth to display your KML/KMZ images.